# Deep equal between a string object and a Promise<string> object in javascript

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

Would it be incorrect to use a deep equal to check the equality of a fulfilled Promise and a string? If this is incorrect, then what is the correct way to check if these values are equal?

Comment: What do you mean by deep equal? === ? Or deep-equal npm package?
If ===, then in Javascript the difference between == and === , is that == allows type coercion, ('1,2' == [1,2] //true) and === doesn't allow type coercion ( '1,2' == [1,2] //false, string is equal only to string). 
Just decide what is better for your case

Comment: You would need to compare the result of the promise. Not the promise itself

Comment: Chai seems to support  testing fulfilled promise values using [`eventually`](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/). I suspect  `deep equality` refers to the type of comparison test used for promise values that are objects after they become fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a promise and a string, they are different objects with different values. You have to compare the resolved promise.

You can use [chais as promise](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) to do that in this way:

```js
it('Test', () => {
  return returnPromise().should.eventually.equal(your_string)
})
```

I've created this complete example, you can check the result:

```js
it('Test ok', () => {
  return returnPromise().should.eventually.equal("hi!")
})

it('Test nok', () => {
  return returnPromise().should.eventually.equal("no hi!")
})

function returnPromise() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("hi!");
  })
}
```

Here, a `promise` with text `hi!` is returned. And only the test will pass if the expected value is the same. So the output is:

```sh
AssertionError: expected 'hi!' to equal 'no hi!'
+ expected - actual

-hi!
+no hi!
```

First test is ok, but second fail. You can see how the comparsion has been done between strings, not between a promise and string.